# Adsense Mobile Hack: Any way to find out what was the last thing echo'd in a PHP script?

Tags: php, echo, adsense

As everyone knows, we are NOT allowed to modify the Adsense PHP script as it is a TOS violation.

One of the sites I work on is mobile, and the Adsense Mobile Ad creation for Device type "**All Phones**" does NOT give you the option for "**Alternate ad**" for some strange reason, yet over 20% of my impressions are NOT displaying an Ad "**(Unmatched ad requests)**".

There is no Adsense support, and I couldn't find any solution to this issue online.

However, I've noticed that when no Adsense for Mobile ad is displayed, Google just echo's `<!-- google_afm -->`.  So all I need to do to force-display an Alternative Ad is to find out when Google echo's `<!-- google_afm -->` and then just display the alternate myself.

Now, this would be VERY easy to do if I could alter the Adsense PHP code in the following line:

```
echo fread($google_ad_handle, 8192);
```

But again, that would be a violation of the TOS and I would risk getting Banned.

Since I am doing an `include` of this script, is there anyway to determine in PHP what was the last thing echo'd by a script?

If not, then are there any other alternatives you can suggest for me to be able to display alternative ads so that I don't waste over 20% of my impressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

  ob_start();
  include "adsense_script.php";
  $output = ob_get_clean();
  if (substr($output,-19) == '<!-- google_afm -->') {
    // display alternate here
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [output buffering control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php). For example:

```
ob_start();
include("/path/to/script.php");
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), like with the include:

```
<?php
    /**
     * include_get_contents
     *
     * include a file and return it's output
     *
     * @param string $path filename of include
     * @return string
     */
    function include_get_contents($path)
    {
        ob_start();
        include($path);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
```